# Where does non-SharePoint content saved to SharePoint via WebDAV end up?

Tags: folder, webdav

Where does non-SharePoint content saved via WebDAV end up? If I use the Windows Explorer to open any site in SharePoint, I can create a folder using the Explorer and add files. But these files aren't visible to SharePoint as far as I can see.

If I add files to *existing* document libraries, I know everything works as if I had added the file via SharePoint.

Are these files part of the content database?

Are these files included in SharePoint Exports and SharePoint Backups?

Is it perhaps even disrecommended to store files this way?

Answer (score 0):

The folder and files are located in the Content Database. The view look similar to file system view but behind the scene there is complex interactions happening with different technologies to make documents which are not present in file systems to view-able using explorer.

The data this get modified etc. will get saved back into the SharePoint Content Database. And hence if you do a backup the changes will also go into the backup.

Comment: Do you have a citation for the Content Database claim? Or some personal experience to divulge? Also, I think the "complex interactions" you refer to are in fact only WebDAV on top of whatever actual storage these files have. :) Also, are you referring to a SQL Server Database backup or an STSAdm backup?

Comment: Its based on my experience and also looking how the files are rendered. Its similar to the way it looks in SharePoint designer left navigation. Both SQL server and STSADM will contain the data. You can try this as a small experiment.